# Codeigniter Call to a member function where() on bool

Tags: codeigniter-3

I tried to set seen to any contact data in database, but when i try that:

```
public function showMessage($id){
        $this->load->model('Message_Model');
        $messageData = $this->Message_Model->selectMessage($id);
        if($messageData[0]->messageIsSeen == 0){
            $this->Message_Model->setSeenToMessage($id);        
        }
        $data = array('messageData' => $messageData[0]);
        $this->load->view('Back/MessageDetail', $data);
    }
```

Model:

```
function setSeenToMessage($id){
        $this->db->update('messages', array('messageIsSeen' => 1))->where('messageId', $id);
        return 1;
    }
```

It throws that error
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it like this change

```
function setSeenToMessage($id){
        $this->db
             ->where('messageId', $id);
             ->update('messages', array('messageIsSeen' => 1))

        return 1;
    }
```

nevertheless, still i don't know how did it works

Comment: You must use `$this->db->where()` before `$this->db->update`. You received bool value because your query has errors. Take a look [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=chaining#updating-data). Btw, it should be: `$this->db->update('messages', array('messageIsSeen' => 1))` in your code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).